# Is there a collapsing component with "showmore" in material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have seen the extensive use of showmore in google design and my guess would be that there would be a component doing that in material ui. so is there one?

it looks like this, if my desicription is wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid not. You can easily create tho.

Comment: yeap, I ended up noticed that. I gonna try alternatives I guess